# Inheriting forms in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have two forms Form1 and Form2. Form2 is inheriting from Form1.

What I need to do is have Form2 the same as Form 1 and add some features to it, other labels and textboxes. However this is giving me problems.

1. I can't access features of Form1 from Form2
2. There are certain features which I deleted from form 1 before I created Form 2 and they are still being inherited in my Form2. I can't delete them from there and I have no idea how they remained there!
3. Also I don't know why, from the time I created this inheritance, Visual Studio is stopping working every time.

Comment: We need to see some code to be able to help.

Comment: Code you BaseForm, and let Form1 and Form2 inherint from it.

Comment: 1. Property on your controls "Modifier" can be changed so you can acces them in form that inhereted the 1st one. 2. what @Jacek said 3. Some code would be nice to see.

Comment: Does it make sense if I create a BaseForm and inherit Form1 and Form2 from it? Cause it crossed my mind.. but it's just that Form1 is like the baseform.. I dont need to add any features to it

Comment: That's not *some* code, that's a *wall* of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the features of Form1 from Form2 because the designer generates the members with private access modifier. To access you must set for members protected access modifier.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can not see private features of Form 1 and you can not change the properties of controls resides in lay out panel like controls.
2. May be designer generate a code which needs regeneration.
3. open another VS and attach to the one your projects is open in it, then press short-key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and check all "thrown" parts. Then open your form and debug your exception.

Comment: I tried re-building the project and now it's worse: Ensure the assemblies has been referenced and that all projects have been built in my Form2

Comment: Can you please remove inheritance, rebuild your project and again add inheritance and report the result?

Comment: I just did this and now It's ok! The things I removed are no longer in Form 2. and Visual Studio is no longer giving errors! Thanks.. if I may ask another question... is it impossible to have a label in Form 2 put over a panel with a background image in Form 1?

Comment: See this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/3e2e77c4-d0c4-4dd1-939b-8fcfb06432e0

visual inheritance is not supported.

Comment: You can search ParentControlDesigner Class and ControlDesigner.EnableDesignMode Method for further information.

Comment: Oh this sucks!! Thanks for your help though and good to know!